# how can i use 'selected' atribute for a <select> in a while loop?

Tags: php, while-loop, html-select, selected

```
 <label for="brand_id">`Select Brand Name :` </label>
    <select name="filter[brand_id]">
    <option value=""></option>
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['filter']['brand_id']) || (isset($_GET['filter']['category_id'])))
    {
        $selected = 'selected';
    }else
    {
        $selected = '';
    }
    while($brandsRow = $resultBrandsRow->`fetch_assoc())` 

        {


             echo '<option value="'.$brandsRow['id'].'" '.$selected.'>'.$brandsRow['brand_name'].'</option>';
            }

    ?>

    </select>
    <label for="category_id">`Select Category Name :` </label>
    <select name="filter[category_id]">
    <option value=""></option>
    <?php
    while($categoriesRow = $resultCategoriesRow->`fetch_assoc())` 

        {

            echo '<option value="'.$categoriesRow['id'].'" '.$selected.'>`'.$categoriesRow['category_name'].'`</option>';
            }

    ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value=">>"/>`
```

After clicking submit, the selected option should be selected. In the preceding example, after option is selected, every time submit is clicked, show the last record from my list, not the chosen option.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example would be this case:

```
<?php
$a = 1;
?>

<select>
    <option value='so and so' <?= ($a === 1) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>
</select>
```

Comment: `<?=` should really be `<?php echo`

Comment: False, <?= is the same thing as <?php echo and shortens it up. There is no performance difference or reliability difference.

Comment: `<?=` or short open tags isn't always enabled by default. While most servers do in fact have it on, there are of course some that do not. If your code ever has to move, it's possible that it will not function without enabling that option. In order to avoid this unnecessary headache, it is advised to use `<?php echo` because that will never be an issue.

Comment: Read the link I sent you as well as the comments.

Comment: ok but i want this to pot it in a while loop like my code. if $a has a value from 1 to 5 selected will be 5. i need to find the id of the selected option and put a condition .